# I can't run a function in a loop for certain amount of time

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, error-handling

ok, so I have this function that consists in a game that will always return a random value,

and the thing is that I want to run this function 10,000 times to receive 10,000 different values, and it works when I run it individually, but when I run it with a loop, it shows me this error:

Loop:

```
premio_acumulado = []

for i in range(10000):
   
   premio_acumulado.append(juego()['premio'])
```

And here's the error it presents:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_22100/4261353443.py in <module>
      3 for i in range(10000):
      4 
----> 5     premio_acumulado.append(juego()['premio'])
      6 
      7 

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_22100/2828093291.py in juego()
     39 
     40 
---> 41     premio = premios[movimientos[-1]]
     42 
     43     movimiento_premio = {'premio': premio, 'secuencia':secuencia, 'movimientos':movimientos }

KeyError: 12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### In short:

The dictionary `premios` doesn't have the `12` key.

There is a possibility that `movimientos[-1]` is equal to `12` inside your function. Thus `premios[movimientos[-1]]` will raise a `KeyError: 12`.

##### Go through the code:

Each time, you are appending either `1` or `2` to `movimientos`.

Then, `casilla` chooses a value from `movimientos[i]` or `movimientos[i] + 1`. After that, `casilla` is appended to `movimientos`.

##### Here is the problem:

For a sufficiently large iteration, If `casilla` keeps choosing `movimientos[i] + 1`, there is a chance that elements in `movimientos` goes beyond `11`. Once that happened, since `12` doesn't exist in `premios`, key error happens.

##### Potential solution:

You may want to use `random.randint()` for choosing a random iteger instead.

```
for i in range(10):

    casilla = random.randint(1, 11)

    movimientos.append(casilla)
```

Also, `juego()['premio']` is unnecessarily complicated. The loop can also be implemented inside the function as well. In this way, you can input a number, `n`, to the function, and the function will run `n` times.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so as I see it, remember I'm not very fluent with this language, and I might not be completely accurate, but:

What I believe is wrong is that, because `premios` only has from 1 - 11 and does not contain "12" as a key, it is giving you an error.

So in this loop:

```
for i in range(10):
       
       casilla = random.choice([movimientos[i],movimientos[i]+1])

       movimientos.append(casilla)
```

Since `primer_movimiento` is returning `random.choice([1, 2])`, `movimientos[i]+1` is not returning from 1, 11 instead it is returning 1, 12.

And since premios does not contain a defenition with 12 as a key, it will give you an error.

Instead replace:

```
for i in range(10):
       
       casilla = random.choice([movimientos[i],movimientos[i]+1])

       movimientos.append(casilla)
```

with

```
for i in range(9):
       
       casilla = random.choice([movimientos[i],movimientos[i]+1])

       movimientos.append(casilla)
```

It is NOT a time issue :)